# Как скопировать данные из .xlsx файла в Google Drive через Google Apps Script в Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

У меня задача такова:
У меня есть папка в Google Drive
В этой папке несколько файлов Excel (.xlsx)
Через Google Apps Script я делаю функцию суть которой копировать из этих файлов данные и переносить их в первую пустую ячейку Google Sheet.

```
function копироватьИВставлять() {
  var папкаНазвание = "Проверка";
  
  var папка = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(папкаНазвание).next();
  var файлы = папка.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);

  while (файлы.hasNext()) {
    var файл = файлы.next();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(файл.getId()));
    var лист = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    var значение = лист.getRange("B1").getValue();
    var пустаяСтрока = 1;
    while (лист.getRange(пустаяСтрока, 1).getValue() !== "") {
      пустаяСтрока++;
    }
    лист.getRange(пустаяСтрока, 1).setValue(значение);
  }
}
```

Но выдает ошибку доступа:
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1jZA_oAyrVMnGdryCwZaucU8B1Uw5yFjb.
Я изначально подумал, что добавь в сервисы Drive API все решится, но ничего не изменилось. Ошибка доступа осталась.

Comment: А разве SpreadsheetApp умеет работать с Excel файлами? Он создан только для работы с Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, [SpreapsheetApp сервис](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) работает только с Google Sheets.

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files

Поэтому Вам нужно сначала преобразовать файл из Excel формата в Google Sheets.
Как вариант, использовать [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (отдельно нужно его подключить, там есть инструкция, если что). Например, вот так:

```
// xlsx - Это файл Excel на Гугл диске {DriveApp.File}
let file = Drive.Files.copy({title: 'tempxlsxtosheet'}, xlsx.getId(), {convert: true}); 
let ssX = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.id);
```

**Upd 04.03.2022**
Сегодня нужно было настроить конвертацию, понадобилось использовать доп. аргумент. Без него не хотело правильно конвертироваться (был .xlsx файл).

```
Drive.Files.copy(
  { title: 'tempxlsxtosheet', mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, 
  file.getId(),
  { convert: true }
);
```